# fixed background image centered on absolute positioned box

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position, fluid-layout

Would anybody help?
I searched for a week here on stackoverflow.com and on Google but I didn't find a solution for my problem. 
As you can guess I'm not expert in CSS and I admit I probably did something wrong, this is why I am willing to change both html file and css file.

---

I have a fluid layout with fixed (absolute positioned) header, footer and sidebar. The content is in a flexible div with a vertical scrollbar. 
I want to put a background image fixed and centered on the div containing scrollable content and a static div at the end of the main content. 
Unfortunately the background image is centered to viewport instead the containing box, no matter what div I use for the background image.

Here is the code:

## HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sus">
<!--Header-->
    </div>
    <div class="totul">
      <div class="coloana">
            <!--Sidebar-->
      </div> 
      <div class="dreapta">     <!--Here I want the fixed centered background image-->
      <div class="continut">ContentRight asdf asdfa dasf asdf asdfd asfasd fdasfasdf dasfsad fdasfds<br /><br />
        asdfsad ff asdf asdfasd
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ullamco laboris nisi duis aute irure dolor. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ullamco laboris nisi consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt in culpa duis aute irure dolor quis nostrud exercitation. Eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Cupidatat non proident, velit esse cillum dolore ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis nostrud exercitation ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ullamco laboris nisi. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Velit esse cillum dolore ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Quis nostrud exercitation eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor velit esse cillum dolore consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui officia deserunt quis nostrud exercitation sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Ut enim ad minim veniam, consectetur adipisicing elit, excepteur sint occaecat. Cupidatat non proident, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mollit anim id est laborum. Sunt in culpa in reprehenderit in voluptate duis aute irure dolor. Ullamco laboris nisi eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut enim ad minim veniam, velit esse cillum dolore excepteur sint occaecat. Duis aute irure dolor ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Qui officia deserunt. Consectetur adipisicing elit, ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ullamco laboris nisi excepteur sint occaecat ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cupidatat non proident, mollit anim id est laborum. Velit esse cillum dolore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut enim ad minim veniam. Ullamco laboris nisi eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor consectetur adipisicing elit. Eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt velit esse cillum dolore in reprehenderit in voluptate. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur sint occaecat eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, velit esse cillum dolore lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Qui officia deserunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamco laboris nisi. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Quis nostrud exercitation lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Consectetur adipisicing elit, in reprehenderit in voluptate cupidatat non proident. Duis aute irure dolor ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt qui officia deserunt ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Velit esse cillum dolore excepteur sint occaecat. Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Quis nostrud exercitation in reprehenderit in voluptate ut enim ad minim veniam. Mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sunt in culpa cupidatat non proident. Ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ullamco laboris nisi consectetur adipisicing elit, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Quis nostrud exercitation ut enim ad minim veniam, in reprehenderit in voluptate. Duis aute irure dolor.</p>
    </div> 
<!--Next block appear only when all the content above was scrolled down--> 
      <div class="parteneri">End of the main content</div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  <div class="subsol">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
```

## CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
background-color:#CCC;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
color: #006;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(imagini/fundal.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
.container {
min-width:800px;
max-width: 1600px;
min-height: 300px;
text-align: justify;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
}
.sus {
background-color:#CCC;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(mici/antet-fundal.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}
.totul {
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
bottom: 10px;
}
.coloana {
background-image: url(col/umplere.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: center top;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 250px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
}
.dreapta {
margin: 0px;
overflow:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
right: 1px;
left: 250px;
vertical-align: middle;
border-right: 1px solid #999;
background-color: #09F;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(imagini/sigla_map.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
z-index: 0;
}
.continut {
padding: 15px;
margin: auto;
width: 97%;
text-align: justify;
z-index: 10;
}
.parteneri {
background-color: #999;
height: 70px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
}
.subsol {
width:100%;
height:10px;
background-color:#CC8C60;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 9px;
color: #F1DFD1;
}
```

---

I can't sleep until I will solve this mystery. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should put this code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and post a link here.  This will provide a working example, so we can see the problem, and it will make it much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the background image centered within the scrollable content area, make the content area's background transparent. Then stack a div with `position:absolute` *behind* the content area, and ensure that it's the same size and position as the content visible viewport.  Then just set `background: center no-repeat url('your/url')` on the background div.

<strike>[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/K6RQk/1/)</strike> [the image used in that example is misleading, because it contains a white bar on the bottom, and so it *looks* shorter than it actually is.  This makes it look like it's not centered vertically, when actually, it is]

[Here is a better example](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/K6RQk/10/) that demonstrates this technique.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
Your example works perfectly. 
I learned much from your technique. 
Now I realize I made some mistakes. For those visitors of this topic who want to learn from my mistakes, I can say the biggest mistake I made is that creating a container for both sidebar and main contain. 
I did so because I need for some pages to get rid of sidebar and I thought if I set display:none for the sidebar I will solve the problem easier. 
Now I know I can do that using your technique and making 0 the left margin of main contain box. 
Finally I can sleep now. I owe you big time.

Comment: If you don't mind and if you have time, i want to learn more from your technique. 
I modified some dimensions in your example on jsFiddle and I noticed some strange results: I made the header 200px tall, the sidebar 250px wide and the footer 10px as I need. 
Of course I adjusted both the .main and .main-bg but the picture is not quite centered anymore vertically. 
Also if I want to set a background color for .main-bg along with the picture, the color remain white. 
Another issue is when I set a padding for .content and I set the .main footer's heigh to 70px and margin-bottom -70px there is gap

Comment: @JediMaster: Post a link to your modified jsFiddle, and I'll be glad to have a look.

Comment: @JediMaster: I just noticed that the image I used in my original example actually has a small white bar on the bottom.  That's why it looks off-center.  [here is a revised example](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/K6RQk/6/) that uses a different image.  It also uses the changed dimensions you listed in your comment ;)

Comment: Work like a charm. 
Thank you again. 
One more issue if you don't mind: when I set padding and text-align:justify to .content and the page is rendered on a screen with resolution bigger than 1024x768 (let's say 1280x1024), there is a gap between text and gray footer in .content no matter the browser but is worse in Chrome. 
It's not a big problem, but if you can find a solution I'll be in your debt. 
Also in Opera is real crazy: the .main > .footer is moved up like there is no margin-bottom: -70px. But once again it's not a big problem. 
I modified your example: http://jsfiddle.net/K6RQk/9/

Comment: It's ok now, I set margin: 1em; for .content > * instead of padding inside .content and I use block elements like <p> or <h1>. 
The problem with Opera remain though despite of last update (version 12.01). 
Any idea?

Comment: @JediMaster: Thanks, I'm glad to help. I don't know about the problem in Opera.  I would have to spend some time testing it, and I don't have a readily available Opera installation right now.  If you do find a solution, please post back with an update, and I'll revise my answer accordingly.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[w3school's definition of background-attachment](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

"background-attachment: fixed" means that your background image will not scroll, at all, ever. It will sit, positioned in relation to your viewport.
Even if it's the background image of a small element on your page, it will stick to the viewport.

You want your background image to affix itself to ".sus", then I recommend you simply remove background-attachment.

Is your background image scrolling with the scrollbar? Then my suggestion would be to wrap your scrolling element in containing div ".sus_wrap" for example, and apply the background to that instead. leave ".sus" transparent, in this case.

but, background-attachment is not what you're looking for.

Comment: I red the definition you mentioned many times before I decided to ask here. They say "The background-attachment property sets whether a background image is fixed or scrolls with the rest of the page." not fixed with the viewport. Maybe I don't understand clearly because my English is not so good, but in the @Lee's example you can see it is possible to attach a background image to an absolute positioned div. Anyway, what I want is to put an image behind the text in main area which is variable and I want it centered to the text. If you can help me with that I will appreciate your effort.

Comment: Your suggestion about making a new div .sus_wrap is very useful but I have no problem with the div .sus. I need a background picture there to fill the header behind the flash menu I put there. 
My problem is with the background picture behind the main content box which is fluid. 
I look forward for any other suggestion. Thank you.